# Soul Speed Boot can't be taken off

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I recieve soul speed boots from a piglin and put them on. It has like a hidden curse of binding on the boots preventing you to take it off until it breaks. Is this intentional behavior,or is there something I need to fix? This happened twice to me already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a [bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-106367). For now, you can put another set of boots in your hotbar and use right click to equip the boots, and then take those boots off normally or leave them on if you would like to.